# OnkeyUp Event on form is processing elements of only onw form even when I am using this in different forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dom-events

I have two forms as below:

```
<li>

    <form name="1" id="gg" method="" >
    <div style="item-list">
    <div class="item-attribute">Oil</div>
    <div class="item-attribute" id="unit" value="40">40</div>
    <div class="item-attribute"><input type="text" style="width:30px;" id="quantity" onkeyup="total()"/></div>
    <div id="total" class="item-attribute"></div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-left:50px;"><input type="submit" value="Add To Cart"/></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</li>

<li>
    <form name="2" id="dg" method="" >
    <div style="item-list">
    <div class="item-attribute">salt</div>
    <div class="item-attribute" id="unit" value="13">13</div>
    <div class="item-attribute"><input type="text" style="width:30px;" id="quantity" onkeyup="total()"/></div>
    <div id="total" class="item-attribute"></div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-left:50px;"><input type="submit" value="Add To Cart"/></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</li>
```

and script that I want to use on onkeyup event in both forms is

```
          function total()
{
var quant=document.getElementById('quantity').this.value;
alert(quant);
var unit=this.document.getElementById('unit').getAttribute('value');

var cost=quant*unit;
 this.document.getElementById('total').innerHTML =cost;
}
```

I want elements of the form in which I enter a number and perform calculations and show up on that form.
But here in second form when the function is being called on onkeyup evet it is taking elemnts of first form and not its own elemnts.

Please help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

An `id` has to be unique across the *document*, not the *form*.
The `document.getElementById()` function will return the first occurrance on the entire document (although the behaviour is technically undefined, but that's how the standard browsers will do it).

Comment: Is there any way to do this where I can get the elements of current form? @UweB

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery pass the ID of form as parameter to the function

```
    <input type="text" style="width:30px;" id="quantity" onkeyup="total('dg')"/>
```

In Javascript

```
function total(id)
{
    var form = document.getElementById(id)
    var quant=form.elements.item('quantity').value;
    alert(quant);
    var unit=form.elements.item('unit').value;

    var cost=quant*unit;
    form.elements.item('total').innerText = cost;
 }
```

Comment: I am not using Jquery..only simple Java Script

Comment: i have edited the answer, you can check if this works for you.

Comment: nope....when I print id in alert it give [ObjectHTMLFormElement]...and when I print form in alert it gives null..but quant is not getting rinted as we doing above

Comment: i am not understanding the problem. Can you create a JSFiddle for this? i will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your element event listener to take the event parameter:

```
<input type="text" style="width:30px;" id="quantity" onkeyup="total(event)"/>
```

Use the target element for the event and navigate around.

```
function total(event) {
    var unit = event.target.parentNode.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
    var qty = event.target.value;
    event.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = unit*qty;
}
```

You should not be using the same id for elements in one document.

Comment: I've updated to get it to work for your example, but this is just to give you some direction, you should try to learn yourself by investigating further.